# FileSystemWatcher doesn't fire for Opened files C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm working with FileSystemWatcher to track opened files. But I have a question, why it doesn't fire the events for opened files. I included Changed, Created, Delete, and Renamed Events but they doesn't fire when files are opened. Well in case of docx it watch a ~!me.docx that is a temporal file. It just works when the file is created or saved.

There is not a Opened event in the class, may be this class is not used to watch opened files??

Can you help me with this issue please. I need to watch just opened files.
I'm using Win7 x64
I have this filters: FileName, attributes, lastAccess, LastWrite,

Comment: You'd have to watch file handles for this,

Comment: You include `changed`, `created`, `deleted` and `renamed` events, but are surprised that you won't receive anything for `opened` files?

Comment: No, you can't use FileSystemWatcher to be notified on OPEN file events. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779616/filesystemwatcher-used-to-watch-for-folder-file-open?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can't use `FileSystemWatcher` for what you want, and you need to work with [Win32 function `ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779729/811785).

Answer (score 0):

The link Steve posted in the comments was useful. FileSystemWatcher watches for opened files, but we have to enable the Lass Access TimeStamp on Windows. Now I have to evaluate the performace of this. Thanks Steve.