# Windows, Watching a folder in C#

Tags: c#, copy-paste, filesystemwatcher

I have a folder which contains some read-only files. I found out that with a so-called WatchService [1][2] I can monitor create, delete or modified events in this folder. But what I need is a notification when a user **opens, copies and/or moves** one of the files inside the folder to a new location.

Is this possible? Can someone point me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

[1] ... [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[2] ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Shouldn't you be watching that folder's parent then?

Comment: I meant if the user opens, copies or moves the files **inside** the folder. I'll clear it up :) thanks

Comment: Copy is a create, move is a delete and create. open is a bit more involved but it's ben asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779616/filesystemwatcher-used-to-watch-for-folder-file-open

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Why is copy a create? The user copies the file **from** my folder into another one (that I'm not watching). Will I get a notification for this?

Comment: nope pretty hard for it to notify you about a new folder you don't know that you aren't watching....